# How to manage/host AWS SQS queue consumers in Python?

Tags: python, message-queue, producer-consumer, amazon-sqs

I am currently working on a distributed processing application written in Python that utilises Amazon SQS.

What is the most Pythonic way of properly creating and hosting a queue consumer in Python that:

- is reliable: if there is a problem and the consumer terminates, some reactive code should be executed and processing should restart
- reuses code: there must be some packages out there to help with this, and it would be great not to have to re-invent the wheel :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [Boto](http://code.google.com/p/boto/)?

> An integrated interface to current and
>   future infrastructural services
>   offered by Amazon Web Services.
>   Currently, this includes:

```
Simple Storage Service (S3)
SimpleQueue Service (SQS)
Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Currently using Boto to interact with SQS. I'm looking for something that is built on/around Boto to implement a reliable consumer/producer system.